# Gitbook external links as blocks

Tags: gitbook

[image]

Does anyone know how to add links in a gitbook documentation like this? Normally, it only allows to link pages that are inside the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the gitbook docs](https://docs.gitbook.com/editing-content/embeds) ?

"To add a rich embed, simply paste the link of the content you want to embed, then press ENTER and voilà ✨."

Comment: Yes I researched further however embed URL does not work if you only want a block link of the link you would like to paste. I believe it is not possible just yet. Thank you!